# as3 Using resized information to scale my movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, resize, scaling

I am working on an air mobile app in Flash CS5.5 and am fairly new at this.

So here is my problem: I placed all of my content inside of a movieClip called base. I have written code to resize my movieClip based on the device it is running on and the devices orientation. That part works fine, the problem is when I tried to create a zoom function.

The base movieClip scales but I am having trouble getting the minimum boundary to work so that my content never scales less than the width of the device. I believe it is referring to the original base width instead of the resized base width. Any ideas on how to call on the new base width after the resize function? Refer to my code below and thank you in advance for any help :)

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

stop();

base.play();

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

var guiSize:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 800);
var appScale:Number = 1;


stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, handleResize);
function handleResize(e:Event):void {
     var deviceSize:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0,  stage.stageWidth, 
     stage.stageHeight);
appScale = deviceSize.width / guiSize.width;
base.width = appScale * guiSize.width; 
base.height = appScale * guiSize.height;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
base.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom); 
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{ 

if (base.scaleX * e.scaleX < 1)
{}
else if (base.scaleX * e.scaleX > 5) 
{}
else {
base.scaleX *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 
       base.scaleY *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2;}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the code and trying many different solutions I came up with the code below and it seems to work fine. The problem was that my base movieClip was scaled up after the resize function which threw off the base.scaleX variable for my zoom function. This is because base.scaleX equals more than one. You can see the problem here:

```
if (base.scaleX * e.scaleX < 1)
```

The code was causing my base movieClip to scale down less than my device window. My solution is to use the new base.width instead to determine minimum and maximum scaleing for my zoom function. As noted below.

```
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{ 
       if (base.width * e.scaleX < deviceSize.width )
       {}
else if (base.width * e.scaleX > deviceSize.width * 2 ) 
{}
else {
base.scaleX *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 
       base.scaleY *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2;}
}
}
```